# laravel pulling data from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm still trying to wrap my head around `whereHas()` method. My case is this. I want to pull all users that belong to class

This is relations

Classes model

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

User model

```
public function classes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classes')->withTimestamps();
}
```

controller

```
$class_us = User::whereHas('classes', function ($query) {
    $query->where('class',1);
})->get();
```

When I do `dd($class_us)` I get an empty collection.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it that `Users` can belongsToMany `Classes` but at the same time the `Classes` hasMany `Users`?

Answer (score 0):

in whereHas clouse the builder instance is coming from the related model so,

```
$class_us = User::whereHas('classes', function ($query) {
            // here the builder belongs to Class model not User model
            $query->where('id',1); // id because classes table has column as id
        })->get();
```

Comment: it's still giving a empty collection

Comment: can you check db if your users_classes intermediate table has atleast 1 record which has class_id = 1 ?